# What is the disjunctive normal form of a formula

Tags: logic

Given a formula A ∧ B, what is the disjunctive normal form of it?

Furthermore, given a formula A, what are the conjunctive and disjunctive normal forms of it?

Comment: See [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form): is a disjunction of conjunctions of *literals* (atoms or negated atoms). Example: $(p \land q) \lor (p \land \lnot r)$

Comment: Given a formula $A$: it depends... You have to write it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  `A`  and `B` are both atoms.

Comment: If they are both atoms, then $A \land B$ is in DNF.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks, I still cannot understand it. It's a subject of a programming standard. Maybe A has the atomic meaning in mathematics.

Comment: "It's a subject of a programming standard" ???? What does it mean? Do you have a textbook?

Comment: See [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form#Definition)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Please take a look at [this sentence](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.order#1). It's a description that should have some mathematical logic knowledge that I don't know. Such as `A ∧ B` mentioned on that page. I have no idea about its disjunctive normal form.

Comment: See footnote 130: A constraint is in Disjunctive Normal Form when it is a *disjunction* of clauses where each clause is a conjunction of atomic constraints. [ *Example*: For atomic constraints A, B, and C, the disjunctive normal form of the constraint $A ∧ (B ∨ C)$  is $(A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ C)$. Its disjunctive clauses are $(A ∧ B)$ and $(A ∧ C)$].

Comment: The green-highlighted statement means that formula $P$ is in DNF and thus is $P_1 \lor  \ldots \lor P_n$ where each disjunctive clause $P_i$ in turn is a conjunction of atoms or negated atoms.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The example has three atomic constraints. I don't know how it would be for two atomic constraints. Such as P is `A ∧ B `, what's the DNF of P?

Comment: $A \land B$ is a DNF with only one disjunct (a "degenerate case") as already said above and in the answer below.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Doesn't the symbol `∧` denote conjunction?

Answer (score 1):

An expression in Disjunctive Normal Form is a disjunction of conjunctions of literals or their negations.

$A\land B$ is a disjunction of one conjunction of two literals.

Thus it *is* in Disjunctive Normal Form.